# ReactJS - How to pass states between one component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-state

I have been trying to make an id scanner attendance system and at some point, I want to pass the value of a state from one component to another sibling component without showing that component in the other sibling component.

Given is the chunk of classroom.js component =>

```
    if (
      this.state.resultBarcode === this.state.stu_enrolno ||
      this.state.alt_enrolment_no === this.state.stu_enrolno
    ) {
      const { stuCardInfoObj, randomNumber } = this.state;
      this.props.firebase
        .facultySubjects(this.state.facKey, this.state.fac_college_name)
        .child(
          `${stuCardInfoObj.SubFacKey}/attendance/${this.state.date}/${randomNumber}/${this.state.stu_uid}`
        )
        .update({
          fname: this.state.profile_name,
          enrolment_no: this.state.stu_enrolno,
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ scanningCardToggle: false, isToggle: false });
          this.props.history.push(ROUTES.ATTENDEES);
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({ barcodeSuccessFailToggle: true });
    }
  }
```

As you can see **`${stuCardInfoObj.SubFacKey}`** on the above 9th line, which is a state. Now, whenever data goes on the firebase and page redirects to its another sibling component called attendees.js using withRouter push history **`this.props.history.push(ROUTES.ATTENDEES)`**,
I want also to pass the value of **`${stuCardInfoObj.SubFacKey}`** in attendee.js without showing the classroom.js component in attendee.js. So, How would I achieve this?

It would mean everything for me if anyone helps me with the above-explained issue.

Comment: Can you share the code for you Classroom and Attendee components and also show where they are being used?

Comment: The short answer is you never share state between siblings. If 2 siblings need to share values, you either lift it up into the parent, or (depending on the use case) into a centralised store like a Redux one. Data should flow *down* the React tree

Comment: How about passing the state in routing : <Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/attendees",
    state: { subFacKey: <your key> }
  }}
/>
or check the context API